# CSS How to get all elements in a table to end at the same spot

Tags: css

I'm trying to align my table so that each team name/logo end at the same point in the table, regardless of the length of the team name. For example, a team with a short name ends sooner than a team with a long name which makes the table unpleasing on the eye.  I want to change it from this.

```
Torino (logo)             VS          (logo) Lazio

Juventus (logo)           VS             (logo) Bologna

Benevento (logo)          VS           (logo) SPAL
```

TO THIS

```
   Torino (logo)       VS          (logo) Lazio

 Juventus (logo)       VS          (logo) Bologna

Benevento (logo)       VS          (logo) SPAL
```

So that regardless of the length of the name, each line is always in line with each other

**JavaScript:**

```
schedule += "<tr>" +
  "<td>" + teamsforschedule[fixtures[i].Homeid - 1].name + "   " + "<img src =" + teamsforschedule[fixtures[i].Homeid - 1].logo +
  " width = 20px height = 35px >" + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + fixtures[i].Homescore + " - " + fixtures[i].Awayscore + "</td>" +
  "<td>" + "<img src =" + teamsforschedule[fixtures[i].Awayid - 1].logo +
  " width = 20px height = 35px >" + "   " + teamsforschedule[fixtures[i].Awayid - 1].name + "</td>" +
  "</tr>"
}
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  table-layout: fixed
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: white;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DFDFDF;
  /* Darken header a bit */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `table-layout` to `fixed` helps here.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td:first-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}
td:first-of-type span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Team Name (logo)</span></td>
    <td>vs</td>
    <td>(logo) Another team</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Medium Team Name (logo)</span></td>
    <td>vs</td>
    <td>(logo) Another team</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Some really long Team Name  (logo)</span></td>
    <td>vs</td>
    <td>(logo) Another team</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `td:first-child` and `td:last-child`. The first child should have `text-align: right;` and the last child should have `text-align: left;`

```css
td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}

td:last-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mj53xer8/)

Comment: In theory this works, but I still want the name and logo to be in the middle though. This just pushes it all the way to either the left or right

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: right;` to change the alignment and select you table column using the `:nth-child`-selector

```css
table {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  table-layout: fixed
}

tr {
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: white;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: right;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DFDFDF;
  /* Darken header a bit */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- taken from here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro as dummy -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```